# best way to deal with multiple intermediate node in a path?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb

basically I have a scenario like the following:

```
vertex --- vertex* --- vertex
```

however the vertex* could have a variable number of vertexes at this point in path resulting in

```
vertex --- vertex1 --- vertex
vertex --- vertex2 --- vertex
vertex --- vertexN --- vertex
```

I won't know what `N` will be until I traverse to this vertex. When I traverse to this node for the first time, arbitrary function will be able to determine how many instances of this vertex will be at this point in path.

do I just record `N` as a property or do I create additional `N` number of paths with middle vertex with incremented value?

A real world example would be, a file directory with unknown number of folders (until you open the parent directory), with each folder containing one file, and you need to traverse each file path.

Update:

This is what I expect:

(first traversal, runs into a vertex with special property *)

```
A --- X* --- B
```

generates additional instance of the same X vertex, connected to parent A, and children B.

```
A --- X1 --- B
 \--- X2 --/
  \-- X3 -/
```

or

```
   A --- X1 --- B
   A --- X2 --- B
   A --- X3 --- B
```

so that now the traversal will happen like

```
A, X1, B
A, X2, B
A, X3, B
```

The `X` vertex instances are exactly same from each other other then that they have an index integer. The number of instances is determined by the first initial traversal (`A, X*, B`). X* may generate 3 or 50 or 100 additional instances.

For storage, what I meant was to store this index value at the X* and increment it everytime until the max integer `N` is reached. So for the above example, it would have a starting index of 1 and max of 3. This would bypass the need to insert additional vertexes in the middle and connect it to both A and B. However, I'm not sure if this is best for my case, which I need to traverse every generated path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i think now i got your use case.

you are right you basically have to options:

1. Replace vertex "x*" by other vertices:

   - First i would execute a simple query searching for all vertices having the special attribute (i would not use a traversal in this step but an index on this special attribute, should be faster)
   - Second i would replace all of them in a transaction with the corresponding amount of real vertices (remember to delete the "x*" vertex if you want to execute this query again)
   - Third you can use all built in traversal statements as the query structure is displayed by the graph.

Pro:

- Simple to implement.
- The data is exactly as you expect it to be, no parsing of attributes necessary, if there are 5 paths from A to B in your Application, there are 5 paths from A to B stored in your DB.
- Can make heavy use of built-in features without (ArangoDB expects all edges to be there physically by default)

Con:

- Redundant data (X1 - Xn are copies of each other) so if you store some data here you have to take care to keep it in sync
- Higher memory consumption.
- More paths in your graph => more traversal steps
- Will be less performant then Option 2.

Option 2: Store only one intermediate vertex and make use of the special attribute

1. Just store vertices X*
2. Implement your own visitor which checks for the special attribute (from your description i think you want to check at vertex B if the last vertex on the path (X*) has the special attribute). If so you add the values for (A X B) n-times to the result.

Pro:

- Performant
- No redundancy

Con:

- You have to implement the logic to replace the X* with X1 - Xn in your application
- You have to implement your own visitor
- There is a slight mismatch between your domain Model and the content in your database

I would make the decision based on the size of your dataset.
If you have a quite small dataset and redundancy/performance is not an issue i would go for option 1 which is much simpler and less effort.
If you have a large dataset and need high performance option 2 would be better i guess.

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

i am a bit confused what you are actually looking for ;)

So first of all could you elaborate your use case further?
Are you searching for the list of all vertices between two vertices `A` and `B`?

```
A --- vertex1 --- B
A --- vertex2 --- B
A --- vertexN --- B
```

Or are you searching for all vertices you can reach from `A` in a specific depth (e.g.: 2):

```
A --- vertex1 --- B
A --- vertex2 --- C
A --- vertexN --- D
```

Second, are you looking for a solution how to store it the best way?
Or are you having it already stored and are looking for a way how to query it?
If you want to query it, what do you expect as a result? The number of paths?
Or the list of in-between vertices?

I think we can solve all the questions above ;)

Comment: I'm basically looking to insert additional vertices between the two outer vertex while traversing through the first path. The middle vertex should create additional number of vertexes connected to A and connected to B. However, I think that to store that many vertices generated while traversing is a waste and maybe it is useful to just store an index on this middle vertex that can be incremented. I will make some updates to the question with what I expect as a result.

Comment: mchacki, I have made some update to my original question hopefully this makes it a bit more clear